# Concatenate Mysql Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

im having problems concatenating this query:

```
$sql.=' WHERE ticket.dept_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getDepts()).') OR ticket.staff_id='.db_input($thisuser->getId());
```

with this:

```
AND ticket.brand_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getBrands())
```

how can i achive this?

Comment: `$sql.= 'AND ticket.brand_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getBrands()).')';` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concat the string on the same-line with:

```
$sql.=' WHERE ticket.dept_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getDepts()).') OR ticket.staff_id='.db_input($thisuser->getId()) . ' AND ticket.brand_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getBrands()) . ')';
```

Or you could do it on a second line:

```
$sql.=' WHERE ticket.dept_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getDepts()).') OR ticket.staff_id='.db_input($thisuser->getId());
$sql.=' AND ticket.brand_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getBrands()) . ')';
```

However, because your original `WHERE` clause contains an `OR`, you'll have to make sure to keep your logic intact. I would suggest to wrap the first two conditions in a single-set of parentheses before concatenating the additional `AND` clause:

```
$sql.=' WHERE (ticket.dept_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getDepts()).') OR ticket.staff_id='.db_input($thisuser->getId()) . ')';
$sql.=' AND ticket.brand_id IN('.implode(',',$thisuser->getBrands()) . ')';
```